# Download file & store file inside an Electrong app

Tags: angular, electron

I have Angular 2 app packaged as Electron app. I wonder if it is possible to download a file via this app and store it inside the Electron package.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by Electron package?

Comment: Well, I mean I have Electron app written in Angular.